# when create CRUD matrix? after ERD, Normalisation or when functional requirements are specified

Tags: oracle11g

When  I have to create CRUD matrix? After conceptual model have been created, or after normalization or when functional requirements are specified?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Depends on what you need the CRUD matrix for. Typically it was used originally to divide a larger administrative system into smaller sub-systems, each of which the functions and entities (tables) have a strong relationship. Of course, there are no hard boundaries because there will be some data shared or you should create totally separate systems. Nowadays I create CRUD-s when I need them: can be for a new system when developing the data model, but can also be for maintenance to make an estimate what parts by a data model change will be influenced. So to answer your question: it depends when you it. When you need it, update or create it.

A handy way to do it is to create a graph (mathematical) in graphml format (XML). Then load that into yEd and ask it to lay out the graph and create groupings. For a small application, a sample is available as [PDF](http://www.invantive.com/en/doc/invantive-producer/invantive-producer-er-diagram-core.pdf) and [Graphml](http://www.invantive.com/en/doc/invantive-producer/invantive-producer-er-diagram-core.graphml)